# What unown letters are available through the Aug. 2017 European event?

Tags: pokemon-go

In the current (August 2017) event going on in Europe, Kangaskhan and Unown are available in Europe, and in large masses. From Trainer Tip's [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3VVQQBfVBS4&t=0s) I've learned that during the Chicago event Unown were also available, but only the letters that spell out "Chicago" ('a', 'c', 'g', 'h', 'i', and 'o') and he said that the same might happen in the current event (only certain letters of Unown being available).

Is this the case, and if so what letters are available and where (since the event takes place in many different cities across Europe)?

Comment: I have no official reference but anecdotally a friend on facebook said the letters were "EUROP" (ie EUROPE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I live in one of the cities where the event takes place, and I've only seen EUROP.

I've seen a screenshot of someone catching another letter (which was the first letter of the city's name), but I'm not sure if that's coincidence. If it's not, then at least those are way rarer than the other letters.

In order of rarity the letters have been occurring roughly as follows for me: E, U, P, O, R. It's not a big difference in rarity, but it's clear that E is much more common than R.

Comment: *I've seen a screenshot of someone catching another letter*. While researching for this question, I found an article mentioning a bug people found that allowed them switch the letter of unown to something random. Niantic fixed the bug with a few hours